# Programmatically render a panels page variant

Tags: 8, panels

There is a Page with id: `front_page`, and a number of variants.

I want to programmatically load the page, evaluate the context and render the appropriate variant.

I have the following code to load the page:

```
$page_id = 'featured_content';
$page_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page');
$variant_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('page_variant');
$page = $page_storage->load($page_id);
// ...
```

How can I build or render the `$page`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how :

```
$page = \Drupal\page_manager\Entity\Page::load('featured_content');
//all variants ids, for the example
$variants = $page->getVariants();
// last variant... could have been $page->getVariant('{VARIANT_ID}');
$pageVariant = end($variants);
$viewer = new \Drupal\page_manager\Entity\PageVariantViewBuilder();
$arr = $viewer->view($pageVariant);
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render($arr);
```

Comment: This renders the page without the theme. How do you render it with the theme wrapper as well?

Comment: Just return $arr on a controller method